Only display the values in a certain rank position from filtered and sorted list



0
A
B




1
100
60


2
50
50


3
80
40


4
10



5
20



6
70



7
30



8
90



9
40



10
60





In Column B I want to 

sort the values in Column A descending and
then only display the values in rank 5,6,7 of the descending order. 

So far I have been able to solve the first step using this formula:
=TAKE(SORT(A1:A10;;-1);5)


However, I have now clue how to implement the second step. It should be something like this
=TAKE(SORT(A1:A10;;-1);5-7)

Do you know which formula I need to only show the values in rank 5,6,7? 
NOTE: The 5,6,7 is just an example for this question. 
It would be great to have formula in which this range can be defined flexible.

The TAKE() wont work that way, have you tried using the CHOOSEROWS()? =CHOOSEROWS(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),5,6,7)

What if there's a tie?

You could try using the CHOOSEROWS() as well:


=CHOOSEROWS(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),5,6,7)


Or, may be using INDEX()
=INDEX(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),{5;6;7})


Addendum: Also, if you ever want to have those list from a filtered data then one possible way:


=LET(α, A2:A11, INDEX(SORT(FILTER(α,MAP(α,LAMBDA(δ,SUBTOTAL(103,δ)))),,-1),SEQUENCE(3,,5)))



Thanks. This already works. Do you know if there is also a solution if you have a bigger file and you want to include ranks from for example 22-45. In the CHOOSEROWS function you would need to enter each number from 22 to 45 separately. Is there a solution where you can apply a range like starting point 22 and ending point 45?

@Michi you would need to use SEQUENCE() --> SEQUENCE(24,,22) and both the ponts within SEQUENCE() can be made dynamic using cell references !! As in the context of your OP: =CHOOSEROWS(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),SEQUENCE(3,,5))

This could be very simple depending on your actual input and requirements. For example, the following could potentially suffice:

Formula in D1:
=LARGE(A1:A10,{5;6;7})


Love the one liner!

There's a couple answers already, but you could also use filter.
=FILTER(SORT(B1:B10,,-1),(ROW(B1:B10)>=5)*(ROW(B1:B10)<=7))

